# Typescript: infer generic types in generic type constraint

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a generic interface that takes a type argument that must extend another generic type.
For example :

```typescript
export interface IPoint<TX, TY>
{
    x: TX;
    y: TY;
}
```

```typescript
export interface ISeries<TPoint extends IPoint>
{
    points: Array<TPoint>;
}
```

Here, I must specify `TX` and `TY` for `IPoint`.

My question is : is there a way to infer those types automatically, for example like this ?

```typescript
export interface ISeries<TPoint extends IPoint<infer TX, infer TY>>
{
    points: Array<TPoint>;
}
```

The only way to make this work I've found for now is to add `TX` and `TY` as type parameters for `ISeries`, but it's quite impractical because then I have to specify the three types every time I use the interface.

I could also use `IPoint<any, any>`, but then I lose the information about the real types of `x` and `y`.

EDIT : To add some clarification about what I want to achieve, let's consider the following example :

```typescript
export interface ISeries<TPoint extends IPoint<infer TX, infer TY>>
{
    points: Array<TPoint>;
    transformYValues?: (yValue: TY) => number;
}
```

Here I would need `TY` to strongly type `transformYValues`.

Thanks for your help

EDIT 2 :
Found a solution (thanks captain-yossarianfromUkraine).

```typescript
export interface ISeries<TPoint extends IPoint<any, any>>
{
    points: Array<TPoint>;
    transformYValues?: (yValue: TPoint['y']) => number;
}
```

The key here is `TPoint['y']`, I wasn't aware of this neat feature called Indexed Access Types (see https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html).

In summary => use `any` typing in the generic type constraints, then use indexed access types to strongly type methods/properties inside the interface.

Comment: Let me know if [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrD6DW) works for you. Please keep in mind that inference mechanism works only with generic conditional types and function arguments

Comment: How would you use this type? It is not clear to me where `x` and `y` would be provided. By "inference" I understand decomposing a type to its constituents, for example `T extends Array<infer U> ? U : never` or `<U>(a: Array<U>) => void` extracts `U` from `Array<Something>`. In the first case the source is `T`, in the second case it's `a`

Comment: @captain-yossarianfromUkraine I edited the question to add an example of a use case, maybe this will help clarify my question. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider this example:

```js
export interface Point<X, Y> {
  x: X;
  y: Y;
}

type Values = string | number

export interface Series<Points extends Point<Values, Values>[]> {
  points: Points;
  transformYValues: (yValue: Points[number]['y']) => number;
}

const inference = <
  X extends Values,
  Y extends Values,
  Points extends Point<X, Y>[]
>(data: Series<[...Points]>) => void 0


inference({
  points: [{ x: 1, y: 2 }, { x: 1, y: 9 }],
  transformYValues: (arg) => {
    arg // 2 | 9
    return 42
  }
})
```

[PLayground](https://tsplay.dev/w6LEGm)

I added `Values` type as a constraint for allowed `x` and `y` data types.

Also, I have added a function `inference` because type inference works with generic conditional types and function arguments.

To infer literal type `x:1 y:2` I have used [variadic tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types), see this `[...Points]`

Comment: @Marc F do you want to allow only `number` type for `x` and `y` ?

Comment: I don't think this helps with my problem, because I need the exact type TY in my interface ISeries. I edited my original question to add an example

Comment: @MarcF made an update

Comment: Tank you, your answer helped find me the solution. I will edit my question to add the solution I found